# Как сделать резиновым только последний элемент списка при вёрстке меню

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Есть меню на основе элементов списка, в последний из которых помещено поле поиска. Элементы списка (точнее, текст в них) могут занимать разную ширину.

Задача - добиться того, чтобы последний элемент списка c формой ввода занимал всё оставшееся место, отведённое под меню.

```css
.menu {
  height: 45px;
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
}

.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu li:not(:last-child) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.menu li.last {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  /* происходит перенос элемента на следующую строку */
}

.menu a {
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  display: inline;
  width: 84%;
  /*  смещение под кнопку .button  */
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  left: -14%;
  width: 12%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2">Text_2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3">Text_123</a></li>
    <li class="last">
      <form class="form">
        <input class="input" type="text"><input class="button" type="submit" value="&#128269;">
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Компоновал разными способами, пытался применить флекс, выносил форму ввода за пределы списка, но результат один из двух: или последний элемент не занимает всё оставшееся пространство, или он переносится на следующую строку.

Прошу совета, что следует исправить, чтобы решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По старинке - таблицей:

```css
.menu {
  height: 45px;
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}

.menu ul {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu li:not(:last-child) {
  width: auto;
}

.menu li.last {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;      
}

.menu a {
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  display: inline;
  width: 84%;
  /*  смещение под кнопку .button  */
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  left: -14%;
  width: 12%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2">Text_2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3">Text_123</a></li>
    <li class="last">
      <form class="form">
        <input class="input" type="text"><input class="button" type="submit" value="&#128269;">
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Flex:

```css
.menu {
  height: 45px;
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li:not(:last-child) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu li.last {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  /* происходит перенос элемента на следующую строку */
}

.menu a {
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  display: inline;
  width: 84%;
  /*  смещение под кнопку .button  */
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  left: -14%;
  width: 12%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2">Text_2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3">Text_123</a></li>
    <li class="last">
      <form class="form">
        <input class="input" type="text"><input class="button" type="submit" value="&#128269;">
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ни первый не второй не резиновый последний элемент и не адаптивный - пример не очень хороший

Answer (score 1):

Вроде так
**исправлено**

пришлось поменять разметку
fiddle: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/xWYdBp?editors=1100

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0 4px;
}

ul,
.items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="search"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form action="">
    <input type="search">
    <button> &#128269; </button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает, ширина поля ввода не меняется и не занимает оставшееся пространство при удалении элемента списка (или изменении его ширины): https://jsfiddle.net/qq7rkgnq/4/

Comment: @118_64 исправил - не сразу понял задачу

Comment: Большое спасибо за рабочий вариант, сожалею, что не могу принять сразу два ответа!